# PHP PayPal header location doesn't work

Tags: php, paypal

i have this PHP code to start a PayPal Sandbox purchase:

```
$querystring = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$querystring .= "?business=" . urlencode($_PayPalApiUsername) . "&amp;";
$querystring .= "item_name=" . urlencode($premium_item["name"]) . "&amp;";
$querystring .= "item_number=" . urlencode($premium_item["number"]) . "&amp;";
$querystring .= "amount=" . urlencode($premium_item["price"]) . "&amp;";
$querystring .= "currency_code=" . urlencode($_PayPalCurrencyCode) . "&amp;";

$querystring .= "cmd=" . urlencode($_POST["cmd"]) . "&amp;";
$querystring .= "payment_key=" . urlencode(generateRandomString(16)) . "&amp;";

$querystring .= "return=" . urlencode(stripslashes($_PayPalReturnURL)) . "&amp;";
$querystring .= "cancel_return=" . urlencode(stripslashes($_PayPalCancelURL)) . "&amp;";
$querystring .= "notify_url=" . urlencode($_PayPalNotifyURL);

header('location:' . $querystring);
exit();
```

At the end `$querystring` contains: `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=business%40email.de&item_name=Starter-Kit&item_number=1000&amount=2.99&currency_code=EUR&cmd=_xclick&payment_key=7qm5en3B253FPxnu&return=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fgame%2Fpremium.php%3Ftask%3Dsuccess&cancel_return=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fgame%2Fpremium.php%3Ftask%3Dcancel&notify_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Faction%2Fnotify_payment_paypal.php` (addresses changed).

If i insert this link manually into the browsers address line, i will be redirected to the PayPal checkout page. So the link should be correct.

BUT if i use `header location` (as seen in the code), i will be redirected to the homepage of PayPal Sandbox (`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/home`).

Does someone knows whats wrong?

Comment: Follow the made HTTP requests (common feature in Chrome, Firefox). Then you can see what exactly the difference is between you browsing the `$querystring` directly vs. having your website redirect you to it.

Comment: Thanks @Maximilian Gerhardt, it seems like the `header location` cant resolve `&amp;`. I replaced them with `&` and it works. Not sure if this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to POST your data to Payments Standard. You're trying to put them all into the query string (GET)

See this [example from PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/)

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="herschelgomez@xyzzyu.com">

<!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

<!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Hot Sauce-12oz Bottle">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.95">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

</form>
```

Comment: But if i call the link manually its GET too, isnt it? I saw many tutorials which are using this code. And they work.

Comment: Got an example of one using GET that you can link?

Comment: i follow this tutorial: [Tutorial](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration)